# Getting The Old Form Input value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to send form input value to next page ( view ) on the form submitted? There is no validation error.

Comment: why don't you add your view, route definition and controller code?? explain `The action is on the same page` with your url or code

Comment: It is search form with 3 input field. I want after result these fields should be filled with old values.

Answer (score 5):

use this:

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

and in view use something like this:

```
<input type='text' name='test' value='{{old('test','DEFAULT VALUE')}}'/>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests

Comment: the action of form on the same page.it will create problem on first time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return back()->withInput($request->input());
```

Comment: `Redirect::back()` can be changed to `redirect()->back()` so there is no Facade needed.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt I've modified my answer

Comment: @btl but would that send back the request input?

Comment: You would need to chain off it: `return back()->withInput($request->input());`

Comment: @btl Oh okay I thought you meant just redirect()->back(). I didn't know you could use just `back()`. Thanks

Comment: Yep, it's one of the [helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-back)